# How to get values from SQL query made by php?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html

So I made a query like this

```
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * 
    FROM streams ";
    $streams_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($streams_set);
```

in my DB there are filds

ID, UID, SID, TIME (all INT type exept time)

So I am triing to print query relult into form

```
          <form>

  <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="SIDs">

           <?php        

    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * 
    FROM streams ";
    $streams_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($streams_set);


            $streams_count = mysql_num_rows($streams_set);
            for ($count=1; $count <= $streams_count; $count++) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$count}\"";
        echo ">{$count}</option>";
    } 
          ?>
          </select>
          <br/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
            </form>
```

How to print out as "option" "values" SID's from my sql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($streams_set)) {
 echo '<option value="'.$row['SID'].'">'.$row['SID'].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form>
  <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="SIDs">
  <?php      

    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * 
    FROM streams ";
    $queryResult = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult)) {          
        echo '<option value="'. $row["id"] .'">'. $row["title"] .'</option>';
    } 
 ?>
 </select>
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
</form>
```

You just have to replace the `id` and `title` index with your appropriate fields.

Answer (score 2):

or mysql_fetch_object()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Answer (score 1):

Ole Jak,
take a look at PHP's mysql_fetch_array http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php, that's what you'll want to do in a while loop :-)